# Crashing in Release Mode and error encounter in Debug Mode

Tags: c++, qt

Its my first question on stack overflow, so please answer me.

I am using libvlc library 2.1.5win64 for window 7 with Qt 4.8.5, C++ and Cmake 2.8 to build a project that capture a streaming video from VLC server in rtsp protocol. I am facing two problems very badly.

> 1: My program is bulding .exe file in Release mode but it crash when we open(double click) this .exe file, while it is working correctly in debug mode.
>
> 2: My program is not working in debug mode also, when I open .exe file it shown a widget but video is not streaming

it encounters a error

```
[0000000001c96b20] main input error: open of 'rtsp"//192.168.1.101:8554/' failed 

[0000000001bcce90] main input error: your input can't be opened
[0000000001bcce90] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.1.101:8554/'. check the log for details.
```

Please somebody anserw my question..............

I am also providing my source code with cmakelist............

If possible please edit my code because i am new on Qt,Cmake,LibVlc

```
CmakeList.txt


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(VlcInterfaceWindow_FULL)
FIND_PACKAGE( Qt4 4.8.5 COMPONENTS QtMain QtCore QtGui REQUIRED )
#SET(VlcInterfaceWindow_SOURCES  main.cpp  vlc_on_qt.cpp)
SET(VlcInterfaceWindow_HEAERS vlc_on_qt.h)

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
include_directories( "C:/vlc-2.1.5/sdk/include")
QT4_WRAP_CPP(VlcInterfaceWindow_HEAERS_MOC ${VlcInterfaceWindow_HEAERS})


add_library(lib_vlc STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib_vlc PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE C:/vlc-2.1.5/sdk/lib/libvlc.lib)
set_property(TARGET lib_vlc PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG C:/vlc-2.1.5/sdk/lib/libvlc.lib)

add_library(lib_vlc_core STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib_vlc_core PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE C:/vlc-    
2.1.5/sdk/lib/libvlccore.lib)
set_property(TARGET lib_vlc_core PROPERTY IMPORTED_DEBUG C:/vlc-2.1.5/sdk/lib/libvlccore.lib)
set(VlcTest_SRCS  main.cpp vlc_on_qt.cpp )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(VlcInterfaceWindow_FULL ${VlcTest_SRCS} ${VlcInterfaceWindow_HEAERS_MOC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(VlcInterfaceWindow_FULL ${QT_LIBRARIES} lib_vlc lib_vlc_core)



main.cpp

#include "vlc_on_qt.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Player p;
p.resize(640,480);
//p.playFile("rtsp://38.117.88.90/TenTV/video");
p.playFile("rtsp://192.168.1.101:8554/");
p.show();
return a.exec();
}





vlc_on_qt.h

#ifndef VLC_ON_QT_H
#define VLC_ON_QT_H

#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <vlc/libvlc.h>
#include <QWidget>

class 
QVBoxLayout;
class
QTimer;
class 
QFrame;
class
QSlider;

#define POSITION_RESOLUTION 10000

class Player : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

QSlider *_positionSlider;
   
QFrame *_videoWidget;
QTimer *poller;
bool _isPlaying;
libvlc_instance_t *_vlcinstance;
libvlc_media_player_t *_mp;
libvlc_media_t *_m;

public:
Player();
```

~Player();

```
public slots:
void playFile(QString file);
void updateInterface();
void changePosition(int newPosition);
};
#endif



vlc_on_qt.cpp

#include "vlc_on_qt.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QFrame>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Player::Player()
: QWidget()
{

 _videoWidget=new QFrame(this);

_positionSlider=new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal,this); 
_positionSlider->setMaximum(POSITION_RESOLUTION);

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(_videoWidget);
layout->addWidget(_positionSlider);
setLayout(layout);

_isPlaying=false;
poller=new QTimer(this);

connect(poller, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(updateInterface()));
connect(_positionSlider, SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)), this, SLOT(changePosition(int)));

poller->start(100); 
}

Player::~Player() 
{
libvlc_media_player_stop (_mp);
   
libvlc_media_player_release (_mp);

libvlc_release (_vlcinstance);

}

void Player::playFile(QString file)
{
 _vlcinstance=libvlc_new(0, NULL);          

 //Create a new LibVLC media descriptor
_m = libvlc_media_new_location(_vlcinstance, file.toAscii());

_mp=libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (_m);


// Get our media instance to use our window 
 libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(_mp, _videoWidget->winId());

// Play 
libvlc_media_player_play (_mp);
  
_isPlaying=true;   

}


void Player::changePosition(int newPosition)
{
libvlc_media_t *curMedia = libvlc_media_player_get_media (_mp);
if (curMedia == NULL)
    return;

float pos=(float)(newPosition)/(float)POSITION_RESOLUTION;
libvlc_media_player_set_position (_mp, pos);

}

void Player::updateInterface()
{
if(!_isPlaying)
    return;

libvlc_media_t *curMedia = libvlc_media_player_get_media (_mp);
if (curMedia == NULL)
    return;

float pos=libvlc_media_player_get_position (_mp);
int siderPos=(int)(pos*(float)(POSITION_RESOLUTION));
_positionSlider->setValue(siderPos);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the log which has been pointed in the error?

Comment: In release you are probably just missing the correct DLLs beside your application. See the deployment chapter in Qt Documentation. This would at least stop your application from crashing in release. This will not solve the problem of not being able to open and play your stream.

Comment: I think I had a similar problem once with libvlc: To me it looks like it is caused by the missing parameters passed to `libvlc_new()`... What's your IDE showing in the output-window, only the lines you've posted in your question? Try to pass the parameter `--verbose=3` to `libvlc_new()` to get more detailed debug-information

Comment: Thanks Robert for comment

Comment: My IDE is Visual Studio 2010

Comment: After passing --vervose=3 the crashing problem remains same. I pass libvlc_new(0,vlc_srgs) where const char * const vlc_args[] = {
              "--verbose=3"
 };

Comment: Since you are passing 0 as number of arguments, the passed parameters are not used at all... Have a look at my answer I've just posted

Comment: If possible..........Please use my code on your pc and provide me some satisfactory answer. Its very important and urgent for me...........

Comment: Thanks Alvaro Gomez for comment. But I am Unable to find this log......

Comment: Im not able to run the code atm, so I've to disappoint you. Have you tried my answer??

Comment: Yes Robert I tried your answer. But I think some other problem are also present here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libvlc.lib from vlc distribution was always broken for use with release Visual Studio builds. To solve this issue you have 3 options:

- Use /OPT:NOREF linker option for release build;
- Generate libvlc.lib from libvlc.dll with Visual Studio's command line tools (with help of [Videolan Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll));
- Use prebuild libvlc.lib [from my libvlc.lib generation project on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/vc-libvlc) or [from my libvlc sdk on GitHub](https://github.com/RSATom/libvlc-sdk);

And to find out what is wrong with video deconding, you could pass "-vvv" (option to activate full debug log) to libvlc_new

Comment: Thanks RSATom for comment. Yes My Plugins problem are solve by setting PLUGINS in environment variable.

Comment: But I want to know where is present this Debug Log. I am unable to find this debug log.

Comment: RSATom one more request to you. please see my CMakeList and suggest me how we can add libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll in my CmakeList

Comment: on Windows you will see debug log in Visual Studio's Output window, or you could use [DebugView from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)

Comment: Why do you want add libvlc.dll to CMakeLists? It's not needed there. You need just something like target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${DEPS_DIR}/libvlc-sdk/lib/msvc/libvlc.lib ). But for application run you have to add libvlc.dll, libvlccore.dll and plugins to your PATH environment variable, or place it near your .exe

Comment: Thanks  RSATom,  PATH environment variable is also working for libvlc.dll & libvlccore.dll. Now I have only One Problem. My rtsp Link is not working till now.

Comment: Thanks RSATom, You solved my many problems. PATH environment variable is also working properly for **libvlc.dll** and **libvlccore.dll**  .

Comment: RSATom one last request to you. Please solve my last problem. My code is working Properly for **HTTP** and **RTP** streaming links, but it gives an error for **RTSP** link...........

Comment: Error is.........._00000000003b7b80] access_realrtsp access warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now [00000000003b7b80] main access debug: no access modules matched [00000000003a3c60] main input error : open of 'rtsp://quicktime.uvm.edu:1554/waw/wdi05hs2b.mov' failed [00000000003a3c60] main input error: your input can't be opened [00000000003a3c60] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://quicktime.uvm.edu:1554/waw/wdi05hs2b.mov'. check the log for details._

Comment: My Play Method code is.........`void Player::playFile(QString file)
{
 const char * const vlc_args[] = { "--verbose=4" };

  _vlcinstance=libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args)/sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);          
    
      _m = libvlc_media_new_location(_vlcinstance, file.toAscii());
    
    _mp=libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (_m);

     libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(_mp, _videoWidget->winId());
    
     libvlc_media_player_play (_mp);
    
    _isPlaying=true;   
}`    Im trying this link (p.playFile("rtsp://quicktime.uvm.edu:1554/waw/wdi05hs2b.mov");). It is working properly in orignal VLC

Comment: Did you try open same link with Vlc player? And replace `const vlc_args[] = { "--verbose=4" }` with `const vlc_args[] = { "-vvv" }`

Comment: yes I tried this link with VLC player. This link is working with VLC player

Comment: This link is working Properly with original  VLC Player, but when I use this in my code it gives the same `Error is.........._00000000003b7b80] access_realrtsp access warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now [00000000003b7b80] main access debug: no access modules matched [00000000003a3c60] main input error : open of 'rtsp://quicktime.uvm.edu:1554/waw/wdi05hs2b.mov' failed [00000000003a3c60] main input error: your input can't be opened [00000000003a3c60] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://quicktime.uvm.edu:1554/waw/wdi05hs2b.mov`

Comment: It's hard to understand what's wrong with your code this way. It will be better if you will push it to github for example...

Comment: RSATom One more things, I want to tell you. In my log some more things are mentiond. 1: could not load \libdshow_plugin.dll   2: could not load \libdshow_plugin.dll  3: could not load \libvlc555_plugin.dll. How could I load these dll files. While all these files are present in my plugins folder

Comment: There is a warning in my log 1: could not load module \libdshow_plugin.dll <The specified module could not be found><error126> 2:could not load module \libdtv_plugin.dll <The specified module could not be found><error126> 3:could not load module \liblive555_plugin.dll <The specified module could not be found><error126>

Comment: Maybe OS can't find some dll dependences. You could try look dependances of not loaded dlls with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Yes, RSATom when I open all three above  mentioned dll files in Dependency Walker. All three gives same error.....**Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.**
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Comment: please make screenshot

Comment: I can not upload a screen shot, because I am new on stackoverflow, and it need at least 10 reputation for uploading a screenshot........

Comment: ok, then let's move our discussion to email. I use gmail with same nick as used here. I hope you understand what I mean.